# Name for a groom, in relation to the best man

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm the best man in a wedding, in a wedding with a groom. However this has lead to an odd conundrum.

The groom can refer to me as *his best man*, however I am unsure of the term I can use for him. He isn't *my groom* as that implies we are getting married.

So is there a term that a best man can use for the groom he is best man to?

Comment: This is an excellent question so have a well-deserved +1. I can find absolutely nothing hinting at a specific word describing this; literally the best I can do is "groom for whom I am best man". Hope you get an answer!

Comment: Are you looking for a term that can still be used ten years from now ("I need some vacation time next month, my ___ is coming to visit"), even if you serve as best man in multiple weddings for multiple grooms during that time? Or are you looking for a term for the duration of the event? If the latter, then -- people normally just say "the groom".

Comment: @ruakh More of the latter.

Comment: I always hear the long-winded "I was best man at his wedding". I'm wondering if bridesmaid/bride have this as well.

Comment: Within the context of the wedding, referring to him as 'the groom' is appropriate, as weddings generally only have one.

Comment: Yep, he’s ***the groom*** and,  typically, ***your best friend*** or ***brother***  etc.

Comment: Even if you found a word (let's say 'XXX'), it isn't going to be appropriate to refer to him as 'my XXX' in the future, because you can be best man to many grooms and thus have many XXXs. At best you are going to be able to call him 'one of my XXX', which frankly is no less complicated than "I was his best man".

Comment: When a buddy of mine got married a few years back, the best man called the groom *sock puppet*... don't know how wide spread it is, but try it, see how you like it :)

Comment: @JohnClifford I wonder whether this arises from relational disparity in a 'short-term' (*occasion*al - i.e. only for the occasion) relationship: compare a sports star saying, "He's my water boy." with the water boy saying, "He's my ___." You could fill the blank with a generic title like *boss*, but not really a reciprocal relational title.

Comment: Maybe we should coin the term "best groom". I don't think there is a specific term for this currently because there wasn't much need for it. P.S. You can ask the same question for the chief bridesmaid.

Comment: Would even the bride saysay "my groom"?  It's often "my newlywed husband"  (don't forget the role is also known as "the bridegroom") Just refer to your role,  "I am XYZ's best man...."

Answer (score 2):

For formal speech you can say "The groom (name)", my dear friend (name) and 
for lighthearted speech and introduction among friends or same aged people you may say my best friend, my friend (his name), (name) who just got married/ who is ready to marry, My brother (name), only (his name). My pal (name), Any designation for male friend and brother you choose with your heart will be understood and appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a word that a best man could use to refer to his relationship with the groom, or better yet the bridegroom?  No, not really.

The more precise and complete term for *[**groom**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groom_(profession))* is ***[bridegroom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridegroom)***, the former does not refer exclusively to the bride's soon-to-be-husband as it can also mean the person who tends to the horses and stables. If outside the church and before the wedding reception the best man referred to his friend as “my groom”  people might think he were talking about his employee; or, they might infer that the OP is speaking about his male partner, and consequently a same-sex marriage was forthcoming. Might... if they didn't know anything about the OP.

Wikipedia explains:

> A bridegroom (sometimes shortened to *groom*) is a man who will soon or has recently been married. A bridegroom is typically attended by a best man and groomsmen.
>
> **Etymology**
>
> The first mention of the term *bridegroom* dates to **1604**, from the Old English *brȳdguma*, a compound of *brȳd* (bride) and *[guma](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/guma#Old_English)* (man, human being, hero). It is related to the Old Saxon *brūdigomo*, the Old High German *brūtigomo*, the German *Bräutigam*, and the Old Norse *brúðgumi*

Interestingly, the term *best man*, first noted in 1814,  is Scottish in origin and replaced the older **[groomsman](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=groomsman)** used since the 1690s.

Traditionally, the groom chose a man who would make sure the bride's family would not recapture her during  the wedding ceremony, he had to stand beside the groom, alert and well-armed. In addition,  he was expected to continue his duty outside the newly-weds' home (presumably until the couple had consummated their marriage).  *[The "best" part of that title refers to his skill with a sword, should the need arise.](http://edition.cnn.com/2008/LIVING/wayoflife/06/27/wedding.traditions/index.html?iref=newssearch)*

As can be seen, the term *bridegroom* is a compound word meaning the *man* or *hero* of the bride. It therefore follows that the groom-to-be cannot also be the ‘man’ or ‘hero’ of the best man. Today the best man is left with the following choices:

- I am best man to [First and last name]
- I am his best man (or traditionally, *groomsman*)
- I am the bridgroom's best man

Answer (score 1):

In speeches at a wedding when I've been the best man I simply called the groom by his name.  At a wedding I think you can assume everyone knows who is getting married or certainly ought to.  In other contexts, as others have pointed out, groom works fine.

Answer (score -1):

You can refer him as "My Friend". I dont think there is any specific word

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. Can you try to include reference or link (that can support your answer) and its essential part? Please take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.